# Move on click - html, css only - media queries

Tags: css, hyperlink, menu, media-queries

I have a link on my menu items and id's on h2 of the text that belong to it. All I want to do is easy - when I click on certain item in the menu I want it to move down to the text that belongs to it. Easy.

I have it like side menu on the left and next to it is the text. When the resolution is under 479px the "side menu" is at the top and the text is under it. And what I want it to do is only when it is under this resolution - to jump down to the text (h2). When is it side by side it is fine and there is no need to do that of course. So my question is.. is it posiible to do so somehow only by using html and css? To make it work ("jump") only when it is under 479px? Media queries somehow?

Thanks you

```
    <section id="budova">
          <div class="materials">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>BUDOVA (izolace)</h1>
            <div class="materials-container">
            <div class="kategorie">
            <a href="#produkty"><h2 data-kategorie="#silsonic" class="active">Silsonic</h2></a>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#mappysil400">Mappysil CR 400</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#mappysil404">Mappysil CR 404</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#polistik">Polistik / M under special HQ</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#pavisol">Pavisol</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#mappysilent">Mappysilent</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#fonosilent">Fonosilent</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#bugnato">Mappysil CR Bugnato</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#mappysil-re">Mappysil CR RE</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#mappypren">Mappypren AU</h2>
            <h2 data-kategorie="#stopfire">Stopfire Bugnato</h2>
          </div>
    
          <div class="produkty" id="produkty">
            <div id="silsonic" class="active">
              <h3>Silsonic</h3>
              <img src="./img/materials/budova/silsonic.jpg" alt="Silsonic">
              <p>Cena od 150 kč vč. DPH</p>
              <p>v 40/š 600/d 1200 mm ( ostatní rozměry v sekci ceník )</p>
              <p>SILSONIC je termoizolační a akusticky absorpční materiál vyrobený z tepelně zpracovaných, recyklovaných polyesterových vláken. Panely SILSONIC se používají k tepelné a zvukové izolaci všech druhů zdiva, sádrokartonových konstrukcí, stropů a pro podstřešní izolace.</p>
              </div>
.
.
. 
more text
```

CSS

```
.materials-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  margin: 3rem 0;
}
.materials h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6rem 0 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.kategorie {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}
.produkty {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; */
  margin-left: 10rem;
}
.produkty div {
  display: none;
}

.produkty div.active {
  display: initial;
}
.produkty h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.produkty p:first-of-type,
.produkty p:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.produkty img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.materials {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.materials p {
  line-height: 24px;
}
.materials h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
.materials h2 {
  width: 70%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.materials h2:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .main-text p {
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
  .main-text h1 {
    padding: 4rem 0 0.5rem;
  }
  .photos img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .photos {
    height: 160px;
  }
  .nav-menu .logo {
    width: 53%;
    height: 52px;
  }
  .materials-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .materials h2 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .kategorie {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
  }
  #fonosilent {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I am not including the code because it is not necessary I think.". No, since including a code example is extremely helpful for us to help you. In fact, Stack Overflow recommends you to put a [minimum and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example in your question.

Comment: Ok I added it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an extra "link" in the html

on small screens one will be hidden (the one without jump-to-link) while the other one (with anchor-tag and jump-to) will be shown.

```
...
        <div class="kategorie">
        <a href="#produkty" class="small-screen"><h2 data-kategorie="#silsonic" class="active">Silsonic</h2></a>
        <h2 data-kategorie="#silconic" class="active big-screen">Silsonic</h2>
...
```

media-queries in css:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .big-screen {
      display: none;
    }
    .small-screen {
      display: grid/flex/whatever;
    }
  }
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .big-screen {
      display: grid/flex/whatever;
    }
    .small-screen {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong sorry for my english. What I ment is when you click on the "Silsonic" for example like it is here it opens text which belongs to it. The menu and the text is next to each other. On small devices it cannot be next to each other so there is no flex or grid but the problem is, when I click on the "Silsonic" the text opens bellow and is no visible so I want it to jump down when I click it. All I can do is to jump always or never but I want it jump only when it is 479px on less because there is no grid from there. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @user1049069 
same procedure: make a second element on the position, where you want it on small screens with the text you want to show by clicking the link. 
add .small-screen class to the one you want to see on small screens and add the .big-screen class to the one you want to see on big screens.

the grid or flex in "display: grid/flex/whatever" are just examples. take a value you need but not "none"